# ¿Cómo se relacionan en base de datos a los clientes ocasionales con un pedido, en un sistema de pedidos online?

Tags: base-de-datos, tablas, relaciones, modelorelacional, buenas-prácticas

Estoy estructurando la base de datos de un sistema de pedidos online, que finaliza con el envío del mismo por medio de whatsapp, y me encontré con la situación de registrar los clientes que, en la mayoría de los casos, requiere que ingresen los datos mínimos necesarios para que puedan recibir su producto, con lo cual no quisiera guardarlos en la misma tabla de los clientes que se registran en el sistema.
¿Cuál es la manera correcta de relacionar la tabla de pedidos para su registración?
Hasta el momento, pensé en las siguientes opciones, pero ninguna considero correcta **(no son opciones para elegir. Solo expongo el trabajo que realicé hasta ahora)**:

1. Lo que comenté en un principio: utilizar la misma tabla de **clientes**, diferenciándolos por un campo para distinguir el tipo de cliente. Lo que no me convence de esta opción es que la tabla quedaría con mucha basura, con registros que se utilizarían solo una vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Crear una nueva tabla de **clientes_ocasionales** o similar, dedicada para este propósito. El problema es que de esta manera, al momento de consultar el detalle de un pedido deberé condicionar la consulta para la tabla **clientes** o **clientes_ocasionales**, según sea el caso, lo cual no se considera una buena práctica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Registrar los datos de los clientes ocasionales en la misma tabla de pedidos. En este caso, el id de la tabla **clientes** sería 0, o un id de cliente que apunte a un cliente genérico con nombre "cliente ocasional", y por otra parte, los detalles se ingresarían en la misma tabla de pedidos. Pienso que este enfoque tampoco es bueno, ya que estaré desnormalizando la estructura, y a su vez, redundándola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Tener una tabla de relación con los 2 campos, con el objetivo de hacer join con ambas tablas de clientes (o crear los campos en la misma tabla de pedidos). Solo completaría el id del cliente correspondiente y realizaría un join con ambas tablas. Además de parecer una mala práctica, ambas tablas de clientes tiene diferentes estructuras como para devolver lo mismo a mi sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me ocurren otros modelos derivados de estos, pero no varían en mucho su concepto.

La verdad, es que no sé si me estoy ahogando en un vaso de agua y la solución es más sencilla, pero hace tiempo que la busco y no la estoy encontrando, al menos no dentro de lo que es considerado buenas prácticas, que es a lo que siempre apunto.

**Aclaro que no es una cuestión de opiniones, sino en llegar a la manera en que se resuelve este tipo de problema.**

Les agradezco de antemano la ayuda que puedan brindarme.
Saludos.

**Información agregada:**

En el primer punto, me refiero a "basura", no por el hecho de que el cliente no sea importante como tal, sino por el hecho de que es conveniente que la tabla de clientes almacenara aquellos con los que el comercio podría volver a tener alguna interacción en el futuro, y por lo tanto de los que manejaría un rango más amplio de información. Este es el punto más importante por el cual normalizaría los datos en una nueva tabla, justamente para no redundar. Como esto no sucede con los clientes ocasionales, que ingresan solo los datos mínimos para recibir el pedido, también había pensado en el tercer caso, debido a que justamente los datos que declaro en la tabla de pedidos son los de los clientes que operarán solo para ese pedido. El problema es que estoy relacionando información similar desde 2 lugares distintos.

**Novedades:**

Planteo un nuevo esquema mejorado, en base a los aportes recibidos:

5. Combinar todos los clientes en una tabla **clientes**, y separar aquellos que son *usuarios* o *miembros*, a través de una tabla de relación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencioné en una respuesta, la contra de este esquema, es que un *cliente ocasional* solo depende del pedido que lo originó, lo cual describe una relación de *composición* con el pedido (si no existe el pedido, no existe el cliente), a diferencia de un cliente *usuario* o *miembro* que mantiene con el pedido una relación de *asociación*, ya que el cliente, además de haber realizado un pedido, es usuario del sistema. A estas relaciones las diagramé en el segundo caso.

Comment: Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo que podría terminar cerrada. Lo que parece más sensanto es la opción 2, una clave importante sería saber de qué modo determinas si es un cliente fijo o un cliente ocasional ¿? Quizá respondiendo a eso se arroje más luz para una solución óptima.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad, no realicé la pregunta con la intención de que me respondan con opiniones, sino con la de obtener una respuesta objetiva basada en la justificación correspondiente. Espero que sea entendida de esta manera. No pido que me respondan como les gustaría más hacer esto, sino a de qué manera se podría solucionar mi inconveniente de una mejor manera que las expuestas, basado en conceptos teóricos, por lo cual también los invito a que reformulen mis puntos si lo creen conveniente.

Comment: Respecto a la forma en que se diferencia un cliente ocasional del cliente fijo, no tiene que ver con la frecuencia de compra, sino con el hecho de que se haya registrado en el sistema, ya que podrías ingresar, y realizar el pedido de algún producto sin registrarte. Por otra parte, la opción de registro (independientemente de donde se realice) permite al cliente obtener beneficios, como el acceso a descuentos y promociones, que visto del lado del comercio es un punto para la fidelización.
Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: de todas las opciones que propones creo que la primera es la mas viable a mi parecer, y cuando te refieres a que la tabla se llenaría de basura entiendo que a la final los usuarios ocasionales no te interesan, algo raro ya que por lo que describes estos usuarios también van a tener un pedido asociado. Pero bueno regresando al caso si no te interesan esos usuarios lo que haría para no tener "basura" es eliminar estos usuarios basado en el campo que agregas para diferenciarlos, este eliminado lo puedes automatizar en un job y lo puedes hacer después de un tiempo prudencial basado en la fecha de

Comment: Quizá lo que necesites entonces es una tabla `miembros`  donde determines los clientes registrados. En cuanto a clientes fijos / ocasionales, si las tablas van a tener las mismas columnas, no tendría demasiado sentido tenerlas separadas, otra cosa sería si de los clientes fijos te interesa guardar cierta información que no interesa guardar de los clientes ocasionales. Son pequeños detalles que deberías precisar en la pregunta, como definir lo que entiendes por *datos basura* en este contexto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No me refería a que no me interesen, ya que en sí los necesito para mantener la historia del pedido. 
Ahora edito la pregunta para agregar información al respecto.

Comment: Buenas, no se si te sirva pero podrías tener una tabla usuarios donde tienes todos tus usuarios registrados (me imagino que existen diferentes tipos - o podría - y no todos son clientes). Luego, deja tu tabla cliente como tal y agrega una relación entre usuario cliente. Si un usuario compra 3 veces sin registrarse y luego se registra, podrías vincular las tres compras anteriores al usuario registrado (viendo el mail por ejemplo). Si quieres obtener todos los clientes registrados tan solo debes hacer el join con la tabla usuarios. slds!

Comment: @A.Cedano Sería lo mismo para cada caso, solo que los *miembros* serían los *clientes*, y los clientes restantes serían los clientes ocasionales. El tema es cómo relacionar el pedido con estas 2 entidades de la mejor manera, sin que luego tenga que hacer cosas raras o que implique malas prácticas para guardar u obtener la información.
Justamente, necesitaría disponer de mayor información para el cliente registrado, aunque esta información abarca a la del cliente ocasional
Ya edité la pregunta para agregar información sobre lo que considero basura.
Gracias.

Comment: Un cliente es un cliente. La regla del negocio es nunca perder un potencial cliente. Manejalos todos en la misma tabla.

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano, @FrancoBerardi y Candid Moe. Con las respuestas de los 3 pude avanzar un poco. Voy a editar la pregunta con las novedades. La contra de este esquema, es que un *cliente ocasional* solo depende del pedido que lo originó, lo cual describe una relación de *composición* con el pedido (si no existe el pedido, no existe el cliente), a diferencia de un cliente *usuario* o *miembro* que mantiene con el pedido una relación de *asociación*, ya que el cliente, además de haber realizado un pedido, es usuario del sistema. A estas relaciones las diagramé en el segundo caso.